# Optimal algorithm for 5-point weighted average in C

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, weighted-average

I want to find the "true" peak position in an array of numbers. After finding the index of the largest value I apply the weighted average to determine the true peak position. This requires two indexes to the left and two to the right. But what if the highest peak is on index 0 or 1, or length-1 and length-2? Right now I use ifs to do bounds checking. Would it be faster to just pad the array with two zeros before and after, which would render the ifs unnecessary?

Comment: You can try both ways and measure.

Comment: Is this the result of an FFT?

Comment: Yes, it is an fft result.

Comment: For an FFT result the correct answer is to pad with zeros.  There is no energy below DC (the bucket 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution depends on the problem.  If the peak is at the first one or two entries of the array, then should the data values to the left be zero or perhaps a reflection of the first one or two elements:

```
index:  -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4
         0  0 12  8  1  2  3   <<A assume this, or

         1  8 12  8  1  2  3   <<B or this
```

Depends on the problem specifics.  The same consideration applies at the end of the array.

In general, if your data is a Poisson distribution then A is probably the best estimate.  If the data is Gaussian, then B is a good assumption.

Comment: For completeness simply repeating the '12' is another option.

Comment: @BenJackson, the issue is how to estimate the value of missing data. You could assume any value for indices -2 and -1, but of all the possible values to assume then justify the choice.

Comment: This edge condition happens all the time in image processing, and common solutions include extending with zero (your "A"), mirroring across the edge (your "B"), extending the edge pixel infinitely (my comment) or wrapping to the opposite edge.  I think the answer to *this* question is going to be influenced on the physical meaning of the samples (a meaning which I suspect exists due to his desire to find the weighted peak, as in an FFT).

Comment: I think I had best results with zeros, actually. I tried repeating but not reflecting. I'll test all the options. Overall, padding seems to make the code nicer and negative indexing works well in C99, so for now I'm going with it. I'll wait to see if Ben provides an answer. If not I'll accept this one.

Comment: @Davorin, getting a correct answer is the most important consideration.  What does the distribution of the data look like?  Can you start taking data a little bit early and get info prior to the peak at index = 0?

Comment: Hm, I don't think I can, it's the result of an FFT. The numbers go from 0 (DC) to Nyquist.

Comment: @Davorin, so the array you are examining are frequency values?  You could increase the number of bins (usually in powers of 2) and thus get a better granularity of lower freqs to the the current left of your peak at f[0].  That is, double the number of FFT bins into f' and f[0] is now spread across f'[0], f'[1], f'[2].

Comment: @Davorin, was just working on an DFT/FT and realized that if your data is in frequency domain and it always seems "piled-up" at the first few indices, then what you are really seeing is something called a "Gibbs ear".  No joke.  Look this up on the web, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If AVG[i] = average of a[i-2] to a[i+2], I like the idea of the
**AVG[1] being the average a[0] to a[3] and

AVG[0] being the average a[0] to a[2].**

---

So create a[-1] and a[-2] to meet these goals then the no-exceptions use of "AVG[i] = average of a[i-2] to a[i+2]" may be used.

Let a[-1] have the value such that average of (a[-1] to a[3]) = average of (a[0] to a[3]).
a[-1] = (a[0] + a[1] + a[2] + a[3])/4

Let a[-2] have the value such that average of (a[-2] to a[2]) = average of (a[0] to a[2]).
a[-2] = (5*a[0] + 5*a[1] + 5*a[2] -3*a[3])/12

The other end works in a similar fashion.